# Code entering a function, but not executing a single line of code inside it in Release version of the application

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a status.txt on the code of a .exe so that other .exe can read this status and do his own stuff based on this status.
The point is that the .exe writing the status.txt is not executing anything inside the function that I created to write this status when I build in Release, it passes throught it as it has absolutly no code inside.
Here it is a sample of what I'm doing in the function I call for writing the status.txt.

```
public static bool Finish(bool WithErrors, bool Canceled)
{
    try
    {
        string Status = WithErrors ? "Error" : (Canceled ? "Aborted" : "Finished");
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine("Directory", "Status.txt"), Status, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        Thread.Sleep(100 + rand.Next(0, 1000));
        return Finalizar(WithErrors, Canceled);
    }
}
```

The .exe does not crashes while running on Debug, also the Status.txt is properly created and everything works fine until building on release, where no matter where I try to put the File.WriteAllText, even outside of the Try. Nothing happens, as if the Function was completely empty. In addition the .exe doesn't crash either, because when I put a log.txt after the calling of the Finish() funciton in the main function, it still writes the log, so Finish() is called, nothing happens and application carries on.

What could possibly be wrong with this function for this to happen?

Comment:  Clean and rebuild?

Comment: Sometimes.. one has to go in DEEP.  What you need sir is MSIL (aka CIL).  You might very well need to read the instructions to see what it is doing.  Step into that function using the dissassembly view and figure out what each instruction is doing.  In 'c' or other low level languages.. we have to do this quite a bit when the optimizer screws something up.

Comment: Actually .. duhh.. @CoolBots suggestion first! .. then my harder one.  You might post the MSIL from the function.  I am sure that some people here can read it.

Comment: Are you calling it in release-build?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas , never did it before. I'll try learning how to do it and give it a go.

Comment: @CoolBots , I did it before asking here